# xtext custom scoping: parameters of function

Tags: eclipse, parameters, xtext, scoping

I am trying to custom scoping, such that if I have something like function in my language that get parameters, I want that those parameters will be visible only until there is semicolon, and out of this scope, I want it to not be visible.

I tried redefine the method getScope() in the file MyDslScopeProvider.xtend

In getScope I did something like this:

```
 if (EclassName=="TypedParam" && EFeatureName=="type" && contextType == "TypedParam"){
        return Scopes.scopeFor(Collections.singleton(context),IScope.NULLSCOPE)
    }
```

This is abviosly doesn't working (It doesn't recognize the parameters). How can I do it?

Moreover, I have another question:
I tried implements methods like:

```
def IScope scope_<EClass name>_<EFeature name>(<context type> context, EReference)
```

Although I printed the names and I made sure I am writing the name correct, those method simply never called. (I copied what was printed from the following code)

```
class DomainmodelScopeProvider extends AbstractDomainmodelScopeProvider {
    override def IScope getScope(EObject context, EReference reference)
    {

        System.out.println("scope_" + reference.getEContainingClass().getName()
             + "_" + reference.getName()
             + "(" + context.eClass().getName() + ", ..)"
        );

        return super.getScope(context,reference);                   
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that with Xtext 2.9+ `AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider` is no longer the default superclass of `YourdslScopeProvider`. You are expected to override `getScope(EObject context, EReference ref)`and do if elsing there. Or you change the superclass manually. Btw you can use the Constants in `YourdslPackage.Literals`instead of using manual string constants.

Comment: Thank Christian for the comment I will use getScope instead of scope_ methods. Regard to my first question, I have in my language something like function that get parameters of type Var (something like: function a(Var v)) but I want that v will be visible only in the scope of the function.. (until there is semicolon)  but I don't know which parameters to send to scope::forScope (which elements and which IScope outer)? Is that something I need to do in MyDslScopeProvider or in my grammar? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont get that Point . You Collect the Stuff for the scope and the outer scope is iscope.nullscope in doubt

Comment: o.k, thanks. I try to implement the getScope function that get EObject context as parameter.  I tried do if elsing there,  but I don't know how to do it without casting (and casting didn't work for me). How can I do it? in every "if" there is different situation, and I want to call the fields of the different types, like you did in the answer to the following question in the scope_ method (but there the parameter is very specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791871/xtext-example-of-a-scoped-object/7812650#7812650

Comment: can you give more context please? why does casting not work?

Comment: and as i said: if you change superclass to abstractdeclarativescopeprovider it will work with scope_

Comment: I have in my language Predicate that have params+=TypedParamList and TypedParamList is
    params+=TypedParam (',' params+=TypedParam)*; and in TypedParam I have 'type' which is cross reference, and I want to do ForScope with all the elements in the current Predicate.. I don't know how to do it because it is get in to the getScope function with context instanceof TypedParam and type is the reference

Comment: Can you please add all needed to reproduce to question

Comment: I have this: `Predicate:
 'predicate' name=ID ('(' params=TypedParamList ')')?
 (':' body=TemporalExpression TOK_SEMI)
 | ('{' body=TemporalExpression '}');
 
 
TypedParamList:
 params+=TypedParam (',' params+=TypedParam)*;

TypedParam:
 (module=[Import] '.')? type=[TypeDef] name=ID; //*****and this is example of my language: ***** predicate boo (tmp counter) :
  next(counter)=counter+1
  
  predicate boo2 (tmp counter) :
  next(counter)=counter+1 `  I want that counter would be visible only in the scope of boo and boo2 (and in both predicate the counter would be different.

Comment: yes. type is reference in TypedParam. and I have somewhere in TemporalExpression pointer=ParamReference. Now, the scoping isn't working and the reference is working. (It thinks that counter in boo and in boo2 is the same object, if I do renaming it's change both )

Comment: then you should test if ereference=yourreference and then have a look at context and its parent hierarchy if it is a Predicate. EcoreUtil.getContainerOfType

Comment: I tried to do like here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664825/xtext-how-to-reference-an-element-of-an-element/37670139#37670139), but I can't do something like context.entityA.features because there are a lot of parsing rules until it's get to the rule with the reference and some of them don't have fields to do "tmp.somethingelse". so I tried to do something like in the next comment it's not working, you have an idea?

Comment: `if(reference==myreference){
  val tmp = EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(context, Predicate);
  if (tmp != null) {
     return Scopes.scopeFor(tmp.eContents);
 }`

Comment: why pred.eContents?

Comment: why not pred.paramlist.params?